# How to safely use a properties file in production to connect to Postgres?

Tags: spring, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, properties-file

So I've been researching on how to connect to postgres safely using a `BasicDataSource` from Apache, a Tomcat webserver, and a spring properties file in a Spring App(`application.properties`/`application.yml`).

Some suggests to encrypt the property file, and then in runtime decrypt it, but I'm not convinced on how that is safe since someone can use the same decryption to decrypt the password from the properties file

Another suggests to use SSL to connect without a password, which I can't find a clear example on how to actually do this, especially when incorporating JDBC through spring Jdbc and `BasicDatasource`.

Another suggests to store an encrpyted password that can't be decrypted from the application server, but can be from the postgres server and thus it's safe.

The last suggestion is encryption with a secret as an Environment Variable which is used in the encryption process and decryption process, but isn't that also just as bad since the hacker can see the environment variables if he/she logged in.

I am unsure of how to accomplish a secure connection to postgres with tomcat that is hosting a Spring Boot Web application(packaged to WAR) and would like to request someone's advice or even better, instructions on how they set it up.

Comment: I'll make sure to do those edits next time, didn't know those highlights existed! Thanks @M. Deinum

Comment: Make the `application.properties` only readable by an administrator / group that can access modify it. That way access in only for those who can see it. Also if you are packaging a WAR (and thus deploying to a container) you might consider JNDI to have a predefined datasource in Tomcat and do a lookup. That way you don't need the credentials in the property files.

Comment: I've never stepped back to think about ACLs from the OS level. Thanks for that, and okay, I can look into that, but would that mean that the password is stored somewhere on tomcat?